# Multiple USB-audio dongles in raspberry pi

Tags: usb, audio, usb-audio

I need to record multiple microphones independently based on external events. I wonder if having a USB hub and multiple USB-audio dongles will allow me to do so.

So my questions are:

- How are these devices recognized by the Rpi?
- Could they be used with sounddevice package independently?
- Is it possible to record them independently and asynchronously?

Comment: This question isn't specific to the Pi, it's the same for any Linux computer. The standard sound framework Linux uses nowadays is ALSA, it supports multiple sound inputs with minimal configuration. You may want to use a sound server as JACK on top of it to have simpler control about what connects with what.